# Onblur event is not getting called in chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement as when the user once completes entering the text field I want to do some operation on that text field.

HTML:

```html
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="convenience_chargespopup" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"  onblur="addZeros()" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="Convinience Charges"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function addZeros() {
        alert('sssssssssss');
    }
});
```

The `addZeros()` function is never being getting called.

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: Is working fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysts21ht/)

Comment: Yes , its working on fiddle , i too checked that , but couldn't able to work that n my screen .

Comment: Well what's different between your screen and the code you posted? Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: You are declaring function inside ready handler scope

Comment: @j08691 i am not getting any errors in my browser console .

Comment: BUT, why are you using ready handler here??? Remove it, make your function available on global scope!

Answer (score 1):

`AddZeros` is scoped inside another function, (your unnecessary DOM ready handler), so is not visible to the attribute-based events.

if using jQuery it is best to *not* use attribute-based events with jQuery... Connect them in jQuery so that the code and event registration are together (also allows multiple handlers per event).

Html:

```
<div class="controls">
   <input type="text" id="convenience_chargespopup" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="Convinience Charges"/>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#convenience_chargespopup').blur(function(){
        alert('sssssssssss');
    }).keypress(function(){
        return isNumber(event)
    });
});
```

Note: I usually prefer the shortcut DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#convenience_chargespopup').blur(function(){
        alert('sssssssssss');
    }).keypress(function(){
        return isNumber(event)
    });
});
```